# How to add click event for button in module of jsontohtml node-js (npm)

Tags: npm, json2html

I am trying to convert JSON to HTML. I am able to create the HTML element and ID attribute. However I can not create the onclick events. I am using the `npm json2htmll.js` npm module.

```
let jsontoHtml: {

                "<>": "div",
                "html": [
                     {
                        "<>": "button",
                        "id":"button1",
                        "onclick": "ButtonClicked()",
                        "text": "Click"
                    }
                ]
            };

let html = json2html.transform({}, jsontoHtml);
```

Current output:

```
</button id="button1">click</button>
```

Expected output:

```
<button id="button1" onclick="buttonClicked()">Click</button>
```

Do you know how I can achieve the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

json2html doesn't support on events using the npm module.  Instead I would look at using the jquery plugin for json2html. You'll be able to add events there that will directly hook into the jquery event.  See this example on [json2html.com](https://json2html.com/docs/#main-attributes-events)

```
{'<>':'button','onclick':function(e){
    //e.event : the jQuery event
    //e.data  : user specified data from the the json2html options variable eventData (see Usage)
    //e.obj   : the source object that we are transforming
    //e.index : the index of the array in which the source object was found
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. But now I commented the functionality of the event not support in a Json2Html npm module. It will produce any issue?

Comment: No whatever comments you made in the code won't show when you render the transform.